# How to check custom exception raised in pytest specific to my case?

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, pytest

I am trying out a simple function and the test case is, to check the raise condtion is working or not. In raise  custom exception message is given. The file name is ***converter.py***.

I am using ***Pytest*** framework and testing it. I want to check if the error is raised and pass the test.

```
def convert_file(list_files):

    if type(list_files) is list:
        do some operations
    else:
        raise Exception("The file type is not a list")
    return True`
```

The test function  wrote for this:

```
def test_convert_file_difference():
    result = converter.convert_file('1.xlxs')
 
    assert pytest.raises("The file type is not a list") == result
```

But i am getting the following error

```
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_converter.py - Exception: The file type is not a list
=============================== 1 error in 0.07s ===============================

Assertion failed
```

I have tried the following approach but still the test case is failing.

```
def test_convert_file_difference():
    with pytest.raises(Exception) as exc:
        converter.convert_file('1.xlxs')
    assert "The file type is not a list" in str(exc.value)
```

I am new to Pytest. Could someone give the right specific code.I want to check in the test condition whether custom error has been occured  and I want to pass the test. how to do that ?

Comment: Why is the second test variant failing? It shouldn't be as it uses the error capturing correctly; please add the error log. Also, raising `Exception` is never a good decision; a `TypeError` is perfectly suitable in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following code snippet for passing this scenario in such a way that we can check for the exception getting caught

```
class TestFunction(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_convert_file(self):
        with pytest.raises(Exception) as e:
            result = convert_file({})
        self.assertEqual(str(e.value), "The file type is not a list")
```

Here I have just passed a dictionary into the function to make sure that it goes into exception. Hope this helps for you.

Comment: This did not work. I got the following error message.             raise Exception("The file type is not a list")
E   Exception: 'The file type is not a list'
------------------------------- Captured stdout --------------------------------
The file type is not a list
=========================== short test summary info ============================
ERROR test_converter.py - Exception: 'The file type is not a list'
=============================== 1 error in 0.07s ===============================

Assertion failed

Assertion failed